# Updating a custom field added in edit customer shipping address

Tags: sales-order, custom, customer-address

I have a custom field added for my customer address :

```
\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory;

public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context) {
  $setup->startSetup();
  $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

  // then add attribute and setup data
  // $customerSetup->addAttribute()

  // then add data
  // ->addData([
  //   'used_in_forms' => [
  //      'adminhtml_customer_address',
  //      'adminhtml_customer',
  //      'customer_address_edit',
  //      'customer_register_address',
  //      'customer_address',
  //     ]
  // ]);

}
```

Now my customers can set/save this fine, but if I try to change the customer's address in the sales order information as an Admin it doesn't work and I can't change it.

Endpoint : /sales/order/address/address_id/{id}/key/{key}

anyone knows how to save it properly?